# Acer Aspire E5-571G shows black screen after Acer logo

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire, safe-mode, black-screen-of-death

I have been on windows 10 for 10 months now. Yesterday, i turned my laptop off and back on, it showed the Acer logo then entered a black screen with just the mouse cursor.

I attempted to go into safe mode but i still got the same black screen. 
I have tried to input the password blindly but it doesn't seem like the laptop is taking any input. 
I have projected it to a television via the HDMI but got the same display as the laptop.

I have even refreshed it. 
I have held down the power button for several seconds while the battery and charger are removed.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst using an HDMI cable, log in and update your VGA drivers and AHCI drivers and see if your problem resolves.

I reckon you could try a clean reinstall and during install, select option to update drivers

Comment: I got the same black screen while connected via HDMI. But i had to perform a clean reinstall of windows. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a mouse cursor it means that Windows bootup has initiated and is stuck due to a hard drive issue or the installation got corrupted. Your best bet would be to do a Recovery process using an USB stick or do a fresh install. I do not think it's any other hardware issue.